# How to remove stuff from lists while running it each time?

Tags: python, list

My prompt is to create a story and insert adjectives and nouns from lists I made. I have to make it in a way so that every time I run the code, the word that the computer picks from the list is different from last time.

My list is

```py
list = [a, b, c]
```

How do I remove an item from the list and make it so every time I run the code, the computer will choose a different item?

Comment: what did u tried so far?

Comment: Do you never want to get the same word twice?
How many words roughly do you think you would amass?
Will you be adding more words than the computer will be 'picking' from the list?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code to shuffle the list and get the value of the last item.

```
import random

mylist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
random.shuffle(mylist)
print(mylist.pop())
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You store the random value in a variable, then use it for printing and whatever else you want.

At the end you call *list*.remove(element) like shown [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/remove)

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ["a", "b", "c"]  
list.remove("b")
```